# Randomly display an element from a file in bundle every time a button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

So I have this big file with more than 600 words. I add them in my array and now I need to randomly show them on the Label. Every time a button is pressed the new random word has to be shown until the timer is ended. I've searched multiple sources for this question but couldn't apply them, because I'm new to this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var wordArray: [String] = []
    var i: Int = 0
    var timer = Timer()
    var totalSecond = 5
    func startTimer() {
         timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     }

     @objc func updateTime() {

        
          if totalSecond != 0 {
             totalSecond -= 1
            timerLabel.text = "\(totalSecond) seconds left"
          } else {
             endTimer()
          }

      }

      func endTimer() {
          timer.invalidate()
      }

      func timeFormatted(_ totalSeconds: Int) -> String {
          let seconds: Int = totalSeconds % 60
          return String(format: "0:%02d", seconds)
      }

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var showWordLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "english_words", withExtension: "txt")!
                do {
                    let string = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
                    wordArray = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
        startTimer()
    }

    
    @IBAction func nextBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How to get a random value? Access the array based on that random value? Assign the value to a label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use swift **4.2 and above**  you can use `randomElement()` It returns an optional to avoid the empty case.

```
    let yourArray = ["one", "two", "three", "Four"]
    if let randomName = yourArray.randomElement() { 
    print(randomName)
}
```

if you use Swift 4.1 or below, you do in this way:

```
let array = ["one", "two", "three", "Four"]
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
print(array[randomIndex])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! However I have some bug that when I start the project showWordLabel disappears. Could you tell me why does it happen?

Comment: Also, is there any correct way to check if there an empty index in the array> I guess my Label disappears because of that however when I checked it I didn't find any empty spaces

Comment: "start the project showWordLabel disappears" you need to check in your code if you have in some place you do hidden your label, if not you need to check your constraints that probably not show well your label.   "is there any correct way to check if there an empty index in the array" what you mean exactly? you can check if your array is empty or not by if (array.count > 0) this means , count the array if is bigger than 0 than array is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not 100% sure I understand you problem here a modified version of your viewController.

See comments in code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var wordArray: [String] = []
    var i: Int = 0
    var timer = Timer()
    var totalSecond = 5
    func startTimer() {
        // Stop old timer
        timer.invalidate()
        
        // Start new timer
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func updateTime() {
        if totalSecond != 0 {
            totalSecond -= 1
            timerLabel.text = "\(totalSecond) seconds left"
        } else {
            endTimer()
        }
    }
    
    func endTimer() {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    
    func timeFormatted(_ totalSeconds: Int) -> String {
        let seconds: Int = totalSeconds % 60
        return String(format: "0:%02d", seconds)
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var showWordLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "english_words", withExtension: "txt")!
        do {
            let string = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
            wordArray = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        startTimer()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func nextBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Fetch random Word from array
        let randomValue = Int.random(in: 0..<wordArray.count)
        let randomWord = wordArray[randomValue]
        
        // Assign to label
        showWordLabel.text = randomWord
        
        // Restart timer
        startTimer()
    }
}
```